# Why are functions and structs in the Mantle API prefixed with "gr"?

Tags: api

I was looking at the [Mantle API documentation](https://www.amd.com/Documents/Mantle-Programming-Guide-and-API-Reference.pdf) and noticed that everything is prefixed with "gr", but it's never explained why the functions are prefixed with it and the letters "gr" do not appear anywhere in the name Mantle.

What does the prefix mean?

Comment: It's speculation but [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcgaming/comments/3xgmz9/vulkan_api_specification_is_complete_and/) suggests that it's perhaps "graphics rendering".

Comment: This is purely speculative, but another low-level, explicit, IHV-specific used the "gr" prefix for its function names: [GLIDE](http://www.gamers.org/dEngine/xf3D/glide/glidepgm.htm).